# Why is there a link under the navbar element?

Tags: html

I am just trying to remove the underline that is on the navbar sub categories (courses, about me). I think it is because there is a href, but I don't know what code to use to get rid of it. I tried using `text-decoration: none` but that didn't work. Also feel free to give me more suggestions on how I can make this website better!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Headings*/


/*Navbar*/

.navbar {
  background-color: #005070;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin: 23px 20px 0px 0px;
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navtext::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.navtext:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.navimg {
  width: 175px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 20px;
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

.navlogin {
  width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 20px 0px 0px;
  animation: fadeIn 4s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html"><img class="navimg" src="Assets/Logo White.png"></a>
  <img class="navlogin" src="Assets/Login.png">
  <a class="navtext" href="Pages/Courses/index.html">Courses</a>
  <a class="navtext" href="Pages/About Me/index.html">About Me</a>
</div>
<div class="head1">
  <h1>Placeholder text</h1>
</div>
<div class="head2">
  <h1>Placeholder text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see an underline

Comment: The underline you mean it's on mouse over?

Comment: It appears on hover, I believe that removing this `background: #fff;` from `navtext::after` will solve the problem but there is more code to clean regarding that underline

Comment: There is a underline even when the mouse isnt hovering over it

Comment: It has an underline on the code even when my mouse isnt hovering over, when I do hover over it creates another set of lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the link in that URL then use below property to that `selector`

```
text-decoration:none;
```

here is the example:

```html
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://google.Com">Google</a>
```

this is an example for your code:

```css
.navtext {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html"><img class="navimg" src="Assets/Logo White.png"></a>
  <img class="navlogin" src="Assets/Login.png">
  <a class="navtext" href="Pages/Courses/index.html">Courses</a>
  <a class="navtext" href="Pages/About Me/index.html">About Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Im a beginner, can you explain using it to that selector? I tried `text-decoration:none;` in `.navbar a` but it didnt work

Comment: It's like whichever class you want the link to be removed you should apply css style to that class as `none`. see the example.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is there a way I can get the `text-decoration=none` to be in the css because I think its a bit to clustered in the html

Comment: Yes, I have added same example from your snippet hope that helps!

Comment: Was it useful???

Comment: I see what you mean by putting it into navtext. That didnt work tho, the other one where it was in the html worked.

Comment: ```.navtext{
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 23px 20px 0px 0px;
    animation: fadeIn 2s;
    text-decoration: none;
}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210177/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-royboi-btw).

Comment: Try adding text-decoration: none !important; to your .navtext to test if something else after that is overriding that.

Comment: I personally suggest not to use `!important` this should be considered as a last option, since it overrides all other property, in OPs case issue is fixed without using `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the underline on mouse over the link, try removing this code from your CSS:

```
.navtext::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.navtext:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .3s;
}
```